# How to set Lambda layer ARN in the functions section of serverless.ts file

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to set the dynamic ARN of the layer in my function in the serverless.ts
I even tried to hard code the ARN as below and only gets errors.
There are only many examples available for yaml but not for ts
Thanks

```
  layers: {
    calulator: {
      path: 'calculator-layer',
      name: '${sls:stage}-cal-layer',
      compatibleRuntimes: ['nodejs16.x'],
      compatibleArchitectures: ['x86_64'],
      description: 'A hello lambda layer for reusing calculate function across lambdas',
      package: {
        include: ['../nodejs/**']
      }
    }
  },
  // import the function via paths
  functions: {
    name: hello,
    layers: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:layer:dev-cal-layer:1'
  },
```

**Compile error for above hard coded ARN**

```
Type 'string' has no properties in common with type '{ name?: string | undefined; events?: ({ __schemaWorkaround__: null; } | { schedule: string | { rate: string[]; enabled?: boolean | undefined; name?: string | undefined; description?: string | undefined; input?: string | ... 2 more ... | undefined; inputPath?: string | undefined; inputTransformer?: { ...; } | undefi...'.ts(2559)
```

Comment: What is the error? I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I also recommend [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do something like:

```
functions: {
    name: hello,
    layers: {
       Ref: 'calculator'
    },
},
```

You can check [here](https://theburningmonk.com/cloudformation-ref-and-getatt-cheatsheet/) what will be the value of the **Ref** to a **Layer**. As far I understood, it will be the ARN you are looking for.

And also the Ref reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html).

Regards!